# How can one model the density of a distribution of choice?

Tags: categorical-data, density-estimation

I'm a bit new to stats, so I may be missing some fundamentals.

I'm interested estimating the density of a discrete distribution, so that I can obtain the probability of an unseen outcome. 
I have historic data from a experiment where individuals choose any name. The experiment was conducted several times. The names and amount of times each name was chosen were recorded. The choices aren't completely random, as individuals have their preferences.

In this experiment, I'm assuming that x is random variable that can take on the value of any name. I would thus like to estimate the density over the distribution of x, such that p(name) would be able to give me the probability that a particular name, not chosen within the experiment, would be chosen if the experiment ran until infinity.

Is density estimation the correct way to do this, and if so how would you do it?

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Because $X$ is discrete (it takes on discrete names as values), it doesn't have a density, but rather a mass function. The most straightforward way of estimating this mass function, or pmf, is to simply estimate the probability of a name as the fraction of times the name was chosen in your data (all these fractions will add up to one, so your estimate is a proper probability mass function). If your data are representative random samples from the population of interest, this estimated pmf will converge to the true one.

If you want to get a sense of the variability of your estimated mass function, you can bootstrap your data.